# How to find the type of an integer which is input in a Java programe

Tags: java, types

If the input is entered of an integer type,then if we are required to find and print out whether it is an int,long,short or byte type or it can't be fitted anywhere then how we figure that out?

Comment: write down some code

Comment: If an input is taken as an Integer, it is of type Integer, and so fits in an int or a long. What do you mean, exactly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have the integer stored in the `long` variable `value`, the following code will work.

```
if(value >= Byte.MIN_VALUE && value <= Byte.MAX_VALUE){
    // It's an integer than can fit inside a byte
}else if(value >= Short.MIN_VALUE && value <= Short.MAX_VALUE){
    // It's an integer than can fit inside a short
}else if(value >= Integer.MIN_VALUE && value <= Integer.MAX_VALUE){
    // It's an integer than can fit inside 32-bits
}else{
    // It's an integer than can fit inside 64-bits
}
```

This code just compares the value to the maximum and minimum values of each numeric primitive in Java.

Comment: the keypoint is: what's the type for `value`?

Comment: @LuigiCortese It's **long**, as I said in the answer...

Comment: maybe you edited the answer, i couldn't read it before. Or I just didn't notice

Answer (score -1):

The primitive wrapper classes like `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer` and `Long` have static constants `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE`. You can compare your value to those to determine if it is within the allowed range for a given type.

Answer (score -1):

A field may be either of primitive or reference type. There are eight primitive types: boolean, byte, short, int, long, char, float, and double. A reference type is anything that is a direct or indirect subclass of `java.lang.Object` including interfaces, arrays, and enumerated types.

```
inpu.getType()
```

Output:

> ```
> Element Type              Encoding     
> boolean                      Z     
> byte                         B   
> char                         C   
> class or interface        Lclassname;  
> double                        D  
> float                         F   
> int                           I  
> long                          J   
> short                         S
> ```

OR

```
field.getType().getName()
```

Returns the name of the entity (class, interface, array class, primitive type, or void) represented by this Class object, as a String